# Add assets in a sencha touch build (ST 2.2.1)

Tags: assets, sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.2

I have Sencha Touch 2.2.1 that includes assets like images, videos and .json's. I put them in the `/resources` folder.

When I build the application with Sencha Cmd like this:

```
sencha app build production
```

the assets are not copied to the destination folder (`build/VSBabyMobile/production/resources`)

There must be a way to configure more assets in `.sencha/sencha.cfg` or in Sencha Cmd, but I can't find the answer in the docs.

Thanks

Comment: Did you include the base `resources` folder as one of the `resources` in your `app.json` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the base `resources` folder as one of the `resources` in your `app.json` file.